# @google-analytics/data package [Vue warn]: Error in setup function: "TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null"

Tags: typescript, vue.js, google-analytics, vite

I am using the `@google-analytics/data` package with my Vue/Vite app. When viewing this page:

```
<script lang="ts" setup>
import { useWebsiteDataStore } from '@/stores/websiteDataStore';
import { computed, onMounted, ref } from 'vue';

const startDate = ref('today');
const endDate = ref('today');

const websiteDataStore = useWebsiteDataStore();
const propertyId = computed(() => websiteDataStore.websites[websiteDataStore.currentWebsiteIndex].analyticsPropertyId);

import { BetaAnalyticsDataClient } from '@google-analytics/data';

const analyticsDataClient = new BetaAnalyticsDataClient();
// Runs a simple report.
async function runReport() {
  const [response] = await analyticsDataClient.runReport({
    property: `properties/${propertyId.value}`,
    dateRanges: [
      {
        startDate: startDate.value,
        endDate: endDate.value,
      },
    ],
    dimensions: [
      {
        name: 'city',
      },
    ],
    metrics: [
      {
        name: 'activeUsers',
      },
    ],
  });

  console.log('Report result:');
  response.rows?.forEach(row => {
    console.log(row.dimensionValues![0], row.metricValues![0]);
  });
}

onMounted(() => {
  runReport();

});
</script>
<template>
  <h1>Stats</h1>
</template>
```

I get this error logged to the console:
`[Vue warn]: Error in setup function: "TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null"`

Similar questions don't apply, as they are not for Vite and it's different than first party packages.